# How to get camera calibration matrices?

Tags: opencv, camera-calibration, orb, slam

I am currently experimenting with [ORB SLAM 2](https://github.com/raulmur/ORB_SLAM2) and a [stereo camera like this](https://www.aliexpress.com/store/product/Synchronous-Dual-Lens-USB-Camera-MJPEG-60fps-960P-Stereo-Mini-Board-Camera-Module-Free-Driver-with/913995_32902154431.html?spm=2114.search0104.3.10.21cf6080ZjqyS3&ws_ab_test=searchweb0_0,searchweb201602_4_10065_10068_10059_10696_100031_10084_10083_10103_451_452_10618_10307_5014715_5014615_10134,searchweb201603_1,ppcSwitch_7&algo_expid=a1d972ba-06b8-4608-aa1c-8b524c55655a-1&algo_pvid=a1d972ba-06b8-4608-aa1c-8b524c55655a&transAbTest=ae803_1&priceBeautifyAB=0). I am using 2.8mm and optionally 3.6mm lenses with a resolution of 640x480 pixels for the left and right camera/image.

ORB SLAM 2 lets me define several distortion/rectifying parameters withing the settings file (*.yaml), such as:

```
fx, fy, cx, cy
k1, k2, p1, p2
```

I conducted the OpenCV camera calibration using a chessboard [like described here](https://docs.opencv.org/2.4/doc/tutorials/calib3d/camera_calibration/camera_calibration.html) (9x7 inner corners and 70mm square length). Later on I used this [automated calibration program from MRPT](https://www.mrpt.org/list-of-mrpt-apps/application_camera-calib/) which gives me the same results with less stumbling blocks.

However, ORB SLAM 2 lets me define these additional parameters for pre-rectifying the images (if I understand this correctly):

```
D: 1x5 Matrix -> Distortion Coefficients aquired from calibration (fx,fy,cx,cy) ?
K: 3x3 Matrix -> Intrinsic Matrix aquired from calibration (k1,k2,p1,p2,k3) ?
R: 3x3 Matrix -> Rectification Transformation ?
P: 3x4 Matrix -> New Projection Matrix ?
```

My questions are the following (see below for an example settings.yaml file):

**A.)** Is my assumption correct, that `D` are the `distortion coefficients` and `K` is the `intrinsic matrix` acquired from the checkboard calibration procedure ?

**B.)** Is defining `fx`, `fy`, `cx`, `cy` in `settings.yaml` sufficient for pre-rectifying the images and successful operation of ORB SLAM 2 ?

**C.)** Do I need `R` and `P` matrices for successful operation of ORB SLAM 2 ?

**D.)** How can I acquired the `R` and `P` matrices? The OpenCV camera calibration procedure with the checkboard does not provide me these matrices, correct ?

Here's an example of the above mentioned `settings.yaml` file of ORB SLAM 2:

```
%YAML:1.0

#--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
# Camera Parameters. Adjust them!
#--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

# Camera calibration and distortion parameters (OpenCV) 
Camera.fx: 646.53807309613160
Camera.fy: 647.36136487241527
Camera.cx: 320.94123353073792
Camera.cy: 219.07092188981900

Camera.k1: -0.43338537102343577
Camera.k2: 0.46801812273859494
Camera.p1: 0.0039978632628183738
Camera.p2: 0.00023265675941025371

Camera.width: 640
Camera.height: 480

# Camera frames per second 
Camera.fps: 20.0

# stereo baseline times fx
Camera.bf: 38.76

# Color order of the images (0: BGR, 1: RGB. It is ignored if images are grayscale)
Camera.RGB: 1

# Close/Far threshold. Baseline times.
ThDepth: 50

#--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
# Stereo Rectification. Only if you need to pre-rectify the images.
# Camera.fx, .fy, etc must be the same as in LEFT.P
#--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
LEFT.width: 640
LEFT.height: 480
LEFT.D: !!opencv-matrix
   rows: 1
   cols: 5
   dt: d
   data:[-0.28340811, 0.07395907, 0.00019359, 1.76187114e-05, 0.0]
LEFT.K: !!opencv-matrix
   rows: 3
   cols: 3
   dt: d
   data: [458.654, 0.0, 367.215, 0.0, 457.296, 248.375, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0]
LEFT.R:  !!opencv-matrix
   rows: 3
   cols: 3
   dt: d
   data: [0.999966347530033, -0.001422739138722922, 0.008079580483432283, 0.001365741834644127, 0.9999741760894847, 0.007055629199258132, -0.008089410156878961, -0.007044357138835809, 0.9999424675829176]
LEFT.P:  !!opencv-matrix
   rows: 3
   cols: 4
   dt: d
   data: [435.2046959714599, 0, 367.4517211914062, 0,  0, 435.2046959714599, 252.2008514404297, 0,  0, 0, 1, 0]

RIGHT.width: 640
RIGHT.height: 480
RIGHT.D: !!opencv-matrix
   rows: 1
   cols: 5
   dt: d
   data:[-0.28368365, 0.07451284, -0.00010473, -3.555907e-05, 0.0]
RIGHT.K: !!opencv-matrix
   rows: 3
   cols: 3
   dt: d
   data: [457.587, 0.0, 379.999, 0.0, 456.134, 255.238, 0.0, 0.0, 1]
RIGHT.R:  !!opencv-matrix
   rows: 3
   cols: 3
   dt: d
   data: [0.9999633526194376, -0.003625811871560086, 0.007755443660172947, 0.003680398547259526, 0.9999684752771629, -0.007035845251224894, -0.007729688520722713, 0.007064130529506649, 0.999945173484644]
RIGHT.P:  !!opencv-matrix
   rows: 3
   cols: 4
   dt: d
   data: [435.2046959714599, 0, 367.4517211914062, -47.90639384423901, 0, 435.2046959714599, 252.2008514404297, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0]

#--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
# ORB Parameters
#--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

# ORB Extractor: Number of features per image
ORBextractor.nFeatures: 800

# ORB Extractor: Scale factor between levels in the scale pyramid   
ORBextractor.scaleFactor: 1.2

# ORB Extractor: Number of levels in the scale pyramid  
ORBextractor.nLevels: 8

# ORB Extractor: Fast threshold
# Image is divided in a grid. At each cell FAST are extracted imposing a minimum response.
# Firstly we impose iniThFAST. If no corners are detected we impose a lower value minThFAST
# You can lower these values if your images have low contrast           
ORBextractor.iniThFAST: 12
ORBextractor.minThFAST: 3

#--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
# Viewer Parameters
#--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Viewer.KeyFrameSize: 0.05
Viewer.KeyFrameLineWidth: 1
Viewer.GraphLineWidth: 0.9
Viewer.PointSize:2
Viewer.CameraSize: 0.08
Viewer.CameraLineWidth: 3
Viewer.ViewpointX: 0
Viewer.ViewpointY: -0.7
Viewer.ViewpointZ: -1.8
Viewer.ViewpointF: 500
```

Comment: Unfortunately I do not know about ORB SLAM so I can not answer your other questions, but I can give information about first question.  
``D: 1x5 matrix: Distortion coefficients k1 k2 p1 p2 k3``, 
``K:  3x3 matrix: Intrinsic parameters [fx, 0, cx; 0, fy, cy; 0, 0, 1]``, 
``R:  3x3 matrix: Probably rectification matrix(same as ROS)``, 
``P:  3x4 matrix: Final projection matrix, this should be able to calculated by using previous matrices if your framework is performing that.``

Comment: Thanks for your help so far. I will further experiment with the values and report back.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In my opinion, there are several calibration toolboxes used for calibrating monocular, stereo or multi-cameras.

The first one is [ros_camera_calibration](http://wiki.ros.org/camera_calibration). when running ORBSLAM, I prefer to use this package to obtain the intrinsic parameters of the single moving camera. The intrinsic parameters and distortion coefficients, and projection matrices would be acquired after moving the calibration board.

the second one, what I recently used is [Kalibr](https://github.com/ethz-asl/kalibr/wiki/downloads). It is not only designed to calibrate multi-cameras but also can calibrate jointly the camera and inertial measurement units(IMU).

Besides, You also can use  [MATLAB](https://ch.mathworks.com/help/vision/single-and-stereo-camera-calibration.html)to get the camera's intrinsic parameters.

As for your questions, here are my imperfect answers.

Q.A:  `K(fx, fy, cx,cy)` stands for the intrinsic parameters of the camera and distortion Coefficients are `k1,k2,p1.p2` separately.

Q.B: as far as I'm concerned, obtaining intrinsic parameters, including fx, fy, cx, cy, are sufficient to run ORBSLAM2 with your own cameras.

Q.C&D, if you choose to use [this ROS package](http://wiki.ros.org/camera_calibration), in the end, you will receive the projection matrix and rectification transformation.

Comment: Thanks for your comprehensive answer!